# Populating SQLite DB from HTTP Server

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, retrofit2

I've encoutered a problem on an Android application.
I'm currently trying to GET data from a Server, which returns JSON (array of objects).
I currently use Retrofit2 as a REST client for this task.
I'm now asking if it's possible to do the same thing to store the List i got from server into sqlite, and possibly update periodically data ?

I've checked on Internet but I didn't really find what I want...

HTTP SERVER <= GET => Android app <= SQL => SQLite

Is there a way to use Retrofit or maybe another library with Retrofit to do the work like this ?

Thanks

EDIT : 
I think i'll use retrofit2 + active Android (using annotations on my model) and use a syncadapter with custom service.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a 3rd party library to persist Java objects to a SQLite database (whether the data comes from JSON does not matter).

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Now, there are some libraries that would probably make this task easier, namely ORMs.

[Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-database/) is currently one of the most popular ORMs.

Comment: Of course you don't need a 3rd party library to use a database. You don't need Retrofit for HTTP, either. You can build the TCP/IP packets manually if you want to. This still does not answer the question.